# RxJS observable of results from chain of functions

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have a function `getC` which depends on the output of `getB` which depends on the output of `getA`.  I want to create an observable `stream`, so that when I subscribe to it I get the output of each function, as shown in the snippet.

Is there an operator in RxJS that will give me the same behaviour as in the snippet?  Or is nesting `switchMap`, `concat` and `of` the only way?

```js
const { concat, from, of } = rxjs
const { switchMap } = rxjs.operators


const getA = async() => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve({
  a: 'A'
}), 500));

const getB = async value => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve({
  a: value.a,
  b: 'B',
}), 500));

const getC = async value => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve({
  a: value.a,
  b: value.b,
  c: 'C',
}), 500));

const stream = from(getA()).pipe(
  switchMap(a => concat(
    of(a),
    from(getB(a)).pipe(
      switchMap(b => concat(
          of(b),
          getC(b)
        )
      )
    )
  ))
);

stream.subscribe(value => {
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@7.3.0/dist/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know your dependencies in advance you can hardcode them in the different streams:

1. `c$` requires the latest emission from `b$`
2. `b$` requires the latest emission from `a$`
3. Run the streams in "order" whilst respecting their dependencies so you end up with three emissions, each (except for the first) depending on the previous one.

```js
const a$ = of('A').pipe(delay(600));
const b$ = of('B').pipe(delay(400), combineLatestWith(a$), map(([b, a]) => a + b));
const c$ = of('C').pipe(delay(200), combineLatestWith(b$), map(([c, b]) => b + c));
concat(a$, b$, c$).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.3.0/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha512-y3JTS47nnpKORJX8Jn1Rlm+QgRIIZHtu3hWxal0e81avPrqUH48yk+aCi+gprT0RMAcpYa0WCkapxe+bpBHD6g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script>
const {of, concat} = rxjs;
const {delay, combineLatestWith, map} = rxjs.operators;
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, I think `combineLatest` is the operator I was looking for.  This way you don't have to nest the declarations.  Note: In RxJS 7 it should be `combineLatestWith`.

Comment: @EdI You're right; I overlooked the deprecation notice. I updated the answer to use `combineLatestWith`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some refactoring to make your function recursive

```
const getValue = (propertyName, value = null) => new Promise(resolve => 
  resolve(value ? {...value, [propertyName]: propertyName.toUpperCase()} : {[propertyName]: propertyName.toUpperCase()})
);
```

Then you can use a magic rxjs operator [EXPAND](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/expand)

```
 import { from, EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
 import { expand } from 'rxjs/operators';


from(getValue('a')).pipe(  
 expand((previousData) => {
     if(!previousData.hasOwnProperty('b')) {
       return from(getValue('b', previousData))
     } else if(!previousData.hasOwnProperty('c')) {
       return from(getValue('c', previousData))
     } else {
       return EMPTY
     }
   }
 )
).subscribe(console.log);
```

HERE is a working code https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-czpotj

[image: Console log result]

Comment: Right. `expand` is another way.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-czpotj?file=index.ts